# Does django project has time delay if i modify some codes?

Tags: django

I was wondering that i always got the wrong message when i corrected my code, but not for long, it would return the right result of my program. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not restarting the [built-in django development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) manually after making the changes:

> The development server automatically reloads Python code for each
>   request, as needed. You don’t need to restart the server for code
>   changes to take effect. However, some actions like adding files don’t
>   trigger a restart, so you’ll have to restart the server in these
>   cases.

As documentation says, sometimes in order to see the changes, you need to restart the server manually.

Also, sometimes Django dev server reloader doesn't see the changes right away and it takes some time for the server to notice changes and trigger restart.  If you see this often, restart the server manually.

Also note that in Django 1.7 kernel signals are used to autoreload the server on linux - this should make it pick up the changes and restart faster:

> Changed in Django 1.7:
>
> If you are using Linux and install pyinotify, kernel signals will be
>   used to autoreload the server (rather than polling file modification
>   timestamps each second). This offers better scaling to large projects,
>   reduction in response time to code modification, more robust change
>   detection, and battery usage reduction.

Comment: Uh, like re-enter'python manage.py runserver'? I always do this after i change my code.

Comment: @CrayonChaney yup, this is what I mean: stop the server (`Ctrl+C`) and run `python manage.py runserver` again. Does it help?

Comment: -Nope, like what i say, i always do this after i change my code, but it always put me into that situation

Comment: @CrayonChaney ok, could you give a concrete example of what is happening? What changes do you make and how Django behaves? Thanks.

Comment: Like the project for studying i have been undertaking. I had defined the 'contact' function in myproject/books/views.py , and add the url into urls.py like "url(r'^contact/$',views.contact)," plus the search path 'from books import views',  but it said "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contact'". And i was so sure that i set the right thing above because before this 'contact' function i test another function named 'search' which settings are exactly the same as above. Next thing i did was comment the whole contact function then uncomment , and it worked. So confused!

Comment: @CrayonChaney ok, are you sure you are saving all of the files after changing them and restarting the server manually?

Comment: Yup,or it will show me another error message saying PAGE NOT FOUND, doesn't it ?  However, it works now. But i can't  bear the time i spend  was on something even didn't exist.